# Improper Integrals: Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Give an example of $f$ and $g$ that are continuous on $[a,\infty)$ for which $\int _a^{\infty}(f(x)+g(x))dx$ converges but neither $\int_a^{\infty} f(x)dx$ nor $\int_a^{\infty} g(x)dx$ converges.

Comment: Take any function $f$ that does not converge in  $[a,+\infty)$, and $g=-f$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $f(x) = x^{-1}, g(x) = -x^{-1}$.

General method of construction: Let $\phi:[a,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a divergent function and $\psi:[a,+\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convergent function. Let $f = \phi + \psi, g = -\phi + \psi$.

Comment: Or $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = -x$.  That seems simpler. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

Take $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x^2}$, $g(x) = -\dfrac{\cos x}{x}$, $a=0$.  Then while the integrals of $f$ and $g$ each diverge over $[0,\infty)$, the integral over $f+g$ converges.